# Add, Edit, Remove items from a List<String>

Tags: c#, list, listview

I have a list of Strings, `List<String>`.

I want to be able to open a form, showing the contents of this list, and allow the user to add, edit, and remove items from the list during run time.

I've been looking at ListView, but it isn't clicking for me. I'm not sure if that's because it isn't the right solution or that I don't get it.

What is the proper solution for what I want to do?

Chuck

Comment: What language or environment are you working in?

Comment: Not sure why it happened.. First line should read I have a list of Strings, List<String>.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, jwismar. I'm still gettin' the hang of doing this.

Comment: Listview or datagridview are probably the controls you would want to use as they have all the features you stated.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in WPF, or legacy Windows Forms?

Comment: Windows Forms. The rest of the application is done in Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `list view` and a `context menu` for your target:
try this code:

```
    List<string> listofstring = new List<string>() {"A","B","C" };
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillLstView();
    }

    private void Additem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listofstring.Add("New Item");
        FillLstView();
    }

    private void RemoveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listofstring.RemoveAt(lstview.FocusedItem.Index);
        EditItem.Enabled = false;
        RemoveItem.Enabled = false;
        FillLstView();
    }

    private void lstview_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            RemoveItem.Enabled = true;
            EditItem.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void EditItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string input = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter Edit", "Title", "Edited", 0, 0);
        if (input != "")
        {
            listofstring[lstview.FocusedItem.Index] = input;
            EditItem.Enabled = false;
            RemoveItem.Enabled = false;
            FillLstView();
        }
    }

    private void FillLstView()
    {
        lstview.Clear();
        foreach (var item in listofstring)
        {
            lstview.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

**Result**

[image]

**[Download Project](http://www.uploadbaz.com/r5tztluu43ax)**